# Collada loader restriction in Three.js

Tags: webgl, three.js, collada

In Three.js, the Collada Loader can't load model with more than about 65000 vertices, I know it is because of a limitation of WebGL, but maybe it is possible to divide the model into different buffers ?
So is there a way to load big Collada models ?

Thanks.

Comment: you could write a filter for [meshtool](https://github.com/pycollada/meshtool) pretty easily to split up objects > 64K

Comment: can you elaborate a little please ?

Comment: Did you take a look at the project? It's very modular - you get a collada object as input and can modify it in place. Email of you're interested in contributing and I can give you more details